# Angular factory "is not a constructor"

Tags: angularjs, factory

I'm trying to create a factory but am getting an error instantiating it. Am I missing something?

> sessionFactory is not a constructor
>
> at new sessionController (sessionController.js:5)

**Controller**

```
angular.module('app').controller('sessionController', ['sessionService', 'sessionFactory', sessionController]);

function sessionController(sessionService, sessionFactory) {
    var vm = this;
    var mySessionFactory = new sessionFactory();
}
```

**Factory**

```
angular.module('app').factory('sessionFactory', ['$window', sessionFactory]);
function sessionFactory($window) {
    return {
        save: save,
        get: get,
        clear: clear
    }

    function save(key, value) {
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }

    function get(key) {
        return $window.sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    }

    function clear() {
        $window.sessionStorage.clear();
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="./app/app.js"></script>
<script src="./app/sessionController.js"></script>
<script src="./app/sessionService.js"></script>
<script src="./app/sessionFactory.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular calls the following factory function once to get a singleton to be used for injection:

```
function sessionFactory($window) {
    return {
        save: save,
        get: get,
        clear: clear
    }

    // ...
}
```

So you are calling `new` on this object:

```
{
    save: save,
    get: get,
    clear: clear
}
```

You don't have to call `new` since you already have the object you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem with this line

```
 var mySessionFactory = new sessionFactory();
```

you don't have to instantiate it just use it directly because it already instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an instance of a factory, you should return a function as follows -

```
angular.module('foo', [])
.factory('Foo', ['$http', function($http) {
  return function() {
    this.x = "Some";
    this.y = "value";

    this.someFunction = function() {
      return this.x + this.y;
    };
  };
}]);
```

And then you can instantiate it using -

```
var factoryObj = new Foo();
```

If you're returning an `object` instead of a (constructor) `function` , then no need to instantiate an object using `new`. You can directly use `sessionFactory`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new sessionFactory(), the sessionFactory have to return a function rather than an object to be used as a Constructor.
So you can return an anonymous function which would return an object.

```
 function sessionFactory($window){

    function save(key, value) {
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }

    function get(key) {
        return $window.sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    }  

    function clear() {
        $window.sessionStorage.clear();
    }
    return function () {
        return {
            save : save,
            get : get,
            clear : clear
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation will work fine.